# Jquery hide text outside block

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am fairly new to Javascript and am trying to write an extension for Chrome. I am struggling with one aspect. Please note that the HTML comes from another webpage over which I have no control so I cannot modify it unless I do it programmatically. Also, I have shown three text items in the example below, but this could be as few as one or many more separated by "br". The HTML is as below:

```
<div class = "cls" id = "1234">
  <quote>...</quote>
  "Text to hide/show 1"
  <br style="font-size: medium; height: auto; line-height: normal;">
  "Text to hide/show 2"
  <br style="font-size: medium; height: auto; line-height: normal;">
  "Text to hide/show 3"
</div>
```

The Javascript code is as follows:

```
function processQuotes() {
  $('.cls quote').each(function() {
    var $quote = $(this);
    var userId = $quote.parent().first().text();    /* For example */

    /* See whether user is blocked */
    if(blockUser[userId]) {
      /* Hide text and br elements */
    } else {
      /* Show text and br elements */
    }

  });
}
```

I want to be able to hide the section from "Text to hide/show 1" to "Text to hide/show 3". I envisaged using the JQuery $var.Hide() and $var.Show() methods but I am struggling with how to get the parts I want to hide into $var.

Any help would be gratefully received.
Thanks,
Richard

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you'd put the texts you want to hide in some container element (div for instance)

Comment: i advice you ti change your structure HTML , you can use a list element to write the text in

Comment: re: `"See whether user is blocked"`... Decisions to block access should always be made on the server, not the client-side.

Comment: Where does $a come from?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Maybe I should clarify that the Javascript is for an extension so I have no control over the HTML source. I know how to do this if the text is inside another structure such as a div. Thanks, Richard

Comment: @Maurice Perry: I think you are on the right track but I have no control over the HTML. If I could inject a "<div>" after the quote block and a "</div>" before the closing div I should be able to extract to a variable and call hide or show on it.

Answer (score 0):

I worte a sample, maybe could help:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class = "cls" id = "1234">
  <quote>...</quote>
  <p style="font-size: medium; height: auto; line-height: normal;">"Text to hide/show 1"</p>
  <br />
  <p style="font-size: medium; height: auto; line-height: normal;">"Text to hide/show 2"</p>
  <br />
  <p>"Text to hide/show 3"</p>
</div>
<script>
for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
    (function(i){
        $("#1234 p").eq(i).click(function(){
            $("#1234 p").show();
            $("#1234 p").eq(i).hide();
        });
    })(i);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion meeming. As I have commented above this is for an extension so I have no control over the HTML. The problem is that the "1234" is a different number each time this occurs in the page. Also my example shows three lines of text separated by br. This could vary from one line without br to several lines with br between them.

Comment: @user3770078 I'm sorry that did not solve the extension problem,but numbers of text and the id could be :    `hideAndshow("#1234 p"); function hideAndshow(_div){ for(var i=0; i<$(_div).size(); i++){ (function(i){ $(_div).eq(i).click(function(){ $(_div).show(); $(_div).eq(i).hide(); }); })(i); } } `